# Simple button click game that measures reaction time. How do i save the fastest time with javascript

Tags: javascript

This is the relevant code section:

var bestTime = 0 ;

```
                if (timeTaken > bestTime) {

                    bestTime = timeTaken;

                    document.getElementById("best").innerHTML = bestTime + "s"

                } else {

                    document.getElementById("best").innerHTML = timeTaken + "s"

                }
```

Wider scope:

```
var end = new Date().getTime();

            var timeTaken = (end - start) / 1000;

            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timeTaken + "s";


                var bestTime = 0 ;


                if (timeTaken > bestTime) {

                    bestTime = timeTaken;

                    document.getElementById("best").innerHTML = bestTime + "s"

                } else {

                    document.getElementById("best").innerHTML = timeTaken + "s"

                }
```

Complete program:

```
<head>

    <title>Reaction Timer</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        #topcontainer {

            width: 100%;
            height: 150px;


        }



        #shape {

            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: ;
            display: none;
            position: relative;


        }







    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="topcontainer">

        <h1>Test Your Reactions!</h1>

        <h2>Click on the boxes and circles as quickly as you can!</h2>

        <h3>Your time: <span id="timer"></span>  </h3>

        <p>Best time: <span id="best"> </span> </p>


    </div>



    <div id="shape"></div>






    <script type="text/javascript">

        var start = new Date().getTime();


        function getRandomColor() {
            var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
            var color = '#';
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
            }
            return color;
        }

        function makeShapeAppear() {

            var top = Math.random() * 400;

            var left = Math.random() * 400;

            var width = Math.random() * 200;

            if (Math.random() > 0.5) {

                document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "50%";

            } else {

                document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "0%";

            }

            document.getElementById("shape").style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();

            document.getElementById("shape").style.top = top + "px";

            document.getElementById("shape").style.left = left + "px";

            document.getElementById("shape").style.height = width + "px";

            document.getElementById("shape").style.width = width + "px";

            document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "block";

            start = new Date().getTime();

        }

        function appearAfterDelay() {

                setTimeout(makeShapeAppear, Math.random() * 2000);

        }

            appearAfterDelay();

         document.getElementById('shape').onclick = function() {

            document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "none";

            var end = new Date().getTime();

            var timeTaken = (end - start) / 1000;

            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timeTaken + "s";


                var bestTime = 0 ;


                if (timeTaken > bestTime) {

                    bestTime = timeTaken;

                    document.getElementById("best").innerHTML = bestTime + "s"

                } else {

                    document.getElementById("best").innerHTML = timeTaken + "s"

                }

            appearAfterDelay();


            } 










    </script>



</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: You want to either save it locally on their pc like so https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp or post it to your webserver and save it to database or file

Comment: Why no just save them to localStorage.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you set the var `bestTime` into the click function. So, at the end of the function the variable will return unset. You can simply fix this by moving

`var bestTime = 0 ;`

at the top of your `<script>` tag.

And why the `bestScore` change if the actual score is bigger than the bestScore? If I make `0.967s` and the top score is `0.678s` why the best score change in `0.967s`? For fix this change this line

```
timeTaken > bestTime
```

in

```
timeTaken < bestTime
```

So your final `if` condition will be

```
if (timeTaken < bestTime || bestTime == 0) {
    bestTime = timeTaken;
    document.getElementById("best").innerHTML = bestTime + "s"
}
```

If you want to save the best time on the user computer you can easly use a lib called `js-cookie`, so, everytime that the user return on your game, he will see his best result ever. So add

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.1.4/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

And in javascript

```
if (timeTaken < bestTime || bestTime == 0) {
        bestTime = timeTaken;
        document.getElementById("best").innerHTML = bestTime + "s";
        Cookies.set('besttime', bestTime, { expires: 7 });
}
```

And at the top of `<script>` tag will be

```
var bestTime = 0;
if (typeof Cookies.get('besttime') !== 'undefined') {
        bestTime = Cookies.get('besttime');
}
```

Don't worry if the cookie aren't working because some browsers for security protocol doesn't allow at local files to save cookie in `file:///` protocol

Answer (score 0):

I found a few errors, here's a list with fixes.

**The final ELSE statement should be**

`document.getElementById("best").innerHTML = bestTime + "s"`

`var bestTime = 0;`

Should ONLY be in one place, right at the top of the `<script>` tag.

A completed code should be

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

```
<title>Reaction Timer</title>

<style type="text/css">

    #topcontainer 
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
    }

    #shape 
    {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: red;
        display: none;
        position: relative;
    }
</style>
```

```
<div id="topcontainer">
    <h1>Test Your Reactions!</h1>
    <h2>Click on the boxes and circles as quickly as you can!</h2>
    <h3>Your time: <span id="timer"></span></h3>
    <p>Best time: <span id="best"> </span></p>
</div>

<div id="shape"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bestTime = 0 ;
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
        {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }
    function makeShapeAppear() 
    {
        var top = Math.random() * 350;
        var left = Math.random() * 750;
        var width = (Math.random() * 200) + 100;
        if (Math.random() > 0.5)
        {
            document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "50%";
        } 
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "0%";
        }

        document.getElementById("shape").style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
        document.getElementById("shape").style.top = top + "px";
        document.getElementById("shape").style.left = left + "px";
        document.getElementById("shape").style.height = width + "px";
        document.getElementById("shape").style.width = width + "px";
        document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "block";
        start = new Date().getTime();
    }

    function appearAfterDelay() 
    {
            setTimeout(makeShapeAppear, Math.random() * 2000);
    }
        appearAfterDelay();
     document.getElementById('shape').onclick = function() 
     {
        document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "none";
        var end = new Date().getTime();
        var timeTaken = (end - start) / 1000;
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timeTaken + "s";
            if (timeTaken < bestTime || bestTime == 0) 
            {
            bestTime = timeTaken;
            document.getElementById("best").innerHTML = bestTime + "s"
            }
            else 
            {
                document.getElementById("best").innerHTML = bestTime + "s"
            }
        appearAfterDelay();
        } 

</script>
```